# Modules error with c++17 and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, module, c++20

I am trying to use c++20 modules in my project, on Visual Studio 2017 and MSVC.

I followed [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp-modules-in-visual-studio-2017/#compiler-switch-for-consuming-standard-library-modules) tutorial to enable experimental modules with c++17 in my project.

My problem is that, when I try to compile my project I get some errors like the following:

```
boost.1.77.0.0\lib\native\include\boost\interprocess\detail\win32_api.hpp(926): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before 'module'
```

I am guessing that this is because with modules enabled `module` become a keyword, and libraries that are using it have problems compiling.

So my question are:

- Do my libraries need to be compatible with modules to take advantage of the latter?
- Do you have some advice to solve the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to play with C++20 modules, please use latest version of Visual Studio 2019 (16.11). In this IDE, modules are supposed to be fully supported. This is **far** to be the case in MSVC 2017, with just has some preliminary support. And of course, use `/std:c++20`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sadly I cannot update to VS2019. But, If I was able to update to VS2019, the first question is still valid, Do my libraries need to be compatible with modules?

Comment: Yes, your libraries need to be compatible with modules to use them. C++20 modules are not at all an automatic (magical) feature, libraries must be carefully designed to work with them. For third party libraries, I guess this will not going to happen before several years.

Comment: The final (C++20) version of modules makes `module` a *contextual* keyword to improve compatibility with code like this.